# How to detect iphone app state changes?

Tags: iphone, automation, background, cocoa-design-patterns, uiapplicationdelegate

I am posting this question (along with the answer) so that other people can benefit from a neat technique I have evolved to have modules automatically detect (and respond to) iOS app state changes.  The (formatted) blog discussion is here [My Blog](http://code-evolution.blogspot.com/2011/02/evolved-code-2-splendid-approach-for.html)

Comment: I strongly recommend re-phrasing this as a true question, and then posting an answer, rather than trying to spam

Comment: Mitchel, You are correct that I forgot to include the question mark in my original post.  Fixed.

Comment: And you responded so quickly that I hadn't had time to post the answer.  I hope you don't feel it is still a spammy post.  :)

Comment: Hmm.  Apparently I did something wrong, but unlike Mitchel's comment (which had specific instructions) the moderators comment doesn't really help me improve my post.  I feel as if I'm being punished for 1) wanting to help others write better code and 2) not knowing the rules around here.  Ah, well.  I tried.

Answer (score 13):

If you google around for solutions to having code execute in response to app state changes, you’ll find code examples where you add in calls to your code into your app delegate, because it gets called whenever the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, or didBecomeActive, or WillEnterBackground.

But let’s say you start working on another app, which re-uses a lot of your code.  Wouldn’t it be nice if you could just copy over some files and get all the functionality, without having to worry about re-wiring up the app delegate methods?

To summarize, we want drop-in modules that, just by the virtue of being in the project, will perform their work, without any additional effort or wiring up.  At this point you may be saying “and I also want unicorns and elves to bring me a pizza”.    Bear with me.

I’m not sure how I missed this when reading the docs, but when iOS applications change state, it isn’t just the app delegate that knows about it.  NSNotifications also get posted for all major state changes.  Here is text taken directly from the api reference:

After calling [applicationDidBecomeActive], the application also posts a UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification notification to give interested objects a chance to respond to the transition.

Similarly, there is a UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification that gets posted immediately after the application finishes launching, and other notifications for entering the background, or entering the foreground.

So this simplifies our code:  instead of having to call

```
 [RobustWebService handleAppBecomingActive]
```

in the app delegate’s implementation of applicationDidBecomeActive, we just have to have RobustWebService respond to UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification.

Now pondering this a moment, you might realize that in order for the RWS class to handle the notification, it has to register as an observer.  That call looks something like

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
Selector:@selector(handleAppBecomeActive)
name:UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification
object :nil]
```

And where can that get done?  Remember, we do not want to touch the app delegate because that would defeat the intent of having a self-contained drop-in module.  If only there were some way to have the addObserver function call happen automatically for the class.  If only…

At this point we have to drop out of “Cocoa” and dig into the underlying technology of Objective-C.  Sure enough, there is a class method, called “load” which, if present in your class definition, will automatically be called when the class is first loaded.  Let’s restate that in code.  If you write this function in any class.m file

```
    + (void) load
    {
                // stuff
    }
```

It will run when the class is loaded by iOS.  Interestingly enough, it is run before your app’s main() routine is called so you have to be very careful about what you try to do!  Most of your app is NOT actually up and running at this point, but you are guaranteed that all frameworks that your class links too will be loaded first.  Frameworks such as NSNotificationCenter, so if you include this in your class.m

```
     + (void) load
     {
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                Selector:@selector(handleAppBecomeActive)
                name:UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification
                object :nil];
     }
```

Then your handleAppBecomeActive method WILL get called when your app becomes active, without you having to do anything other than include the class.h and class.m in your project.

And if you include this code in your class.m file

```
+ (void) load;
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(handleAppLaunched)
     name:UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self         selector:@selector(handleAppResigningActive) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleAppBecomingActive) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleAppEnteringBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleAppEnteringForeground) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleAppClosing) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];
}
```

Your class will get notified of all app state changes, with no other work required.  This is so cool that it still makes me feel tingly.   Enjoy!

Terry

Comment: Woah, suddenly I like iOS development a little bit more. Thanks man